# Mix HTML and non-HTML strings in Rails ERB

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a text-area where some users can input HTML (please, no comment about this being unsafe, I already have sanitized countermeasures).

Now, I want to show an example of html code my user can write. How do I do that in my .erb template file with ruby?

The visual output for the end user should look like this (Without syntax highlighting, respect line breaks !)

`my_example_string` :

```
Here is an example of sample code you can write in the text-area:
<p>Hello, dear Mr. X, new announcement</p>
<br>
<h2>The project</h2>
<p>blablabla</p>
<h2>Your role</h2>
<p>...</p>
```

**EDIT** : the actual HTML output looks like

```
<p>
        Here is an example of sample code you can write in the text-area: !&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Hello, dear Mr. X, new announcement;/p&gt;
&lt;h2&gt;The project&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Blablabla&lt;/p&gt;
...
</p>
```

I have tried something like

```
<%= 'Here is an example of sample code you can write in the text-area:' +'<br>'.html_safe + 
    '<br>' + '<br>'.html_safe + 
    '<p>Hello, dear Mr. X, new announcement</p>'+'<br>'.html_safe + 
    '<h2>The project'</h2>' + ... %>
```

But the output looks like (one single line)

```
Here is an example of sample code you can write in the text-area:<br><br><br><p>Hello, dear Mr. X, new announcement</p><br><h2>The project</h2>
```

Apparently I can't mix `.html_safe` and non `.html_safe` string

Any idea ?

**EDIT 2** :

I am actually using a custom helper/renderer which takes this pseudo-tooltip `my_example_string` as an argument

*my_view.html.erb*

```
...
<%= render 'shared/field_with_tooltip',
        field: f.text_area(:body, placeholder: '', class: 'form-control', value: (@body if @body)),
        label: 'Body of the message',
        info: my_example_string %>
```

My `field_with_tooltip` uses the info variable like this

*shared/field_with_tooltip.html.erb*

```
...
<% if info %>
    <p class="text-info field-info"><%= info %></p><br>
<% end %>
...
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of what it should look like on the page? (Plain text is fine.)

Comment: Emm.. the visual output is what I wrote in my first code block. You mean you want the HTML output ?

Comment: Sorry! I was skimming the question and did not realize!

Comment: Do you have capabilities of embedded code blocks? If not, I can provide an answer for you today.

Comment: One more thing, the visual output is a block of text, right? Not the _processed_ code (like showing an actual header)?

Comment: Not sure of what you mean ? Basically, I want to show some tooltip of what a user can write in a text area. For more readability of the tooltip, I want to include linebreaks, even though this doesn't matter in the actual HTML that is written in the text-area.

Comment: That will be a large tooltip. I think it would be best to havethe text box on the right side, and on the left show the sample of what they can enter.

Comment: Yeah ok, I will eventually try several options and see what looks best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short of just writing the HTML entities themselves using `&lt;` and `&gt;`, thus avoiding Rails from having to do the work:

```
<%= ('Here is an example of sample code you can write in the text-area:<br>' + 
h('<br>') + '<br>' + 
h('<p>Hello, dear Mr. X, new announcement</p>')+'<br>' + 
h('<h2>The project</h2>') + ...).html_safe %>
```

This uses the [`html_escape`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape) helper to turn the HTML you want to render into the entities, and then you can call `html_safe` on the entire resulting string to avoid the problems you'd normally run into with the HTMLSafe buffer.

I'd probably clean it up by just avoiding `html_safe` altogether and using the built-in escaping that Rails does:

```
Here is an example of sample code you can write in the text-area:<br>
<%= '<br>' %><br>
<%= '<p>Hello, dear Mr. X, new announcement</p>' %><br>
<%= '<h2>The project</h2>' %>
```

The latter approach is much cleaner.

Comment: Actually I am using a helper function to display the tooltip/example, and it takes a the example as a string argument, which is why I needed your first example featuring the `h()` method :D

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of [`html_safe`](http://devdocs.io/rails/string#method-i-html_safe) is to take a normal string and process it into HTML, following the tags inside the string. For example, this is a `check_box` element, where the label will be processed into **bold text**:

```
<%= f.check_box :BLOCK, label: "<strong>Click to enable</strong>".html_safe%>
```

Just to review, `html_safe` took a string that *included* HTML, and processed it into *working HTML*. Without `html_safe`, The label would be the string itself. (`<strong>Click to enable</strong>`)

Whether you want your text inside a tooltip is up to you. I would recommend not, because tooltips are usually small for short text. I would recommend having the sample user input on the left or right of the text area element. This way, the user can refer to it if necessary, without hovering over the text area.

No matter your design, the following should work with your desired output. Notice, I did not use `html_safe`, because you want to show the raw code to the user, and not the processed code. (Meaning, you do not want to show headers to the user.)

```
<p>Here is an example of sample code you can write in the text-area:</p>
<ul style="list-style: none;">
  <li><code><%='<h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>'%></code></li>
  <li><code><%='<p>Here, you can submit code samples.</p>'%></code></li>
  <li><code><%='<p>Just enter your HTML code in the box!</p>'%></code></li>
  <li><code><%='<p>When you are done, hit Submit.</p>'%></code></li>
</ul>
```

At the moment, I cannot find an ERB fiddle site. You can imagine the text above to look *similar* to the following. (The SO editor is limited):

> Here is an example of sample code you can write in the text-area:
>
> `<h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>`
>
> `<p>Here, you can submit code samples.</p>`
>
> `<p>Just enter your HTML code in the box!</p>`
>
> `<p>When you are done, hit Submit.</p>`

And just to compare, if you used `html_safe`, this is how it would look:

> Here is an example of sample code you can write in the text-area:
>
> ## Welcome to my website!
>
> Here, you can submit code samples.
>
> Just enter your HTML code in the box!
>
> When you are done, hit Submit.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually use some helper which lets me feed some tooltip/info, and I needed to put my example in a single string, so with a single Ruby object

Comment: Okay, I will leave this up, as it answers your question, assuming there is no helper. (You did not mention a helper in the question.)